# Loading JSON from local dynatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, dynatable

I'm trying to do something very similar to the last comment of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297192/load-remote-json-from-dynatable) - that is to load a whole bunch of data in an ajax call but then put it into dynatable as though it's a local JSON file. I am none to proficient at javascript/jquery, so it's probably something fairly obvious, but I can't get it to work. My current code looks like this:

```
<table id="my-ajax-table">
  <thead>
    <th>Some Attribute</th>
    <th>Some Other Attribute</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script>

$.getJSON('/dynatable-ajax.json', function(data) {
      $('#my-ajax-table').dynatable({
      dataset: {
        records: data
      });
    });
```

and the ajax url returns this:

```
[
{"someOtherAttribute": "Fetched by AJAX", "someAttribute": "I am record one"},
{"someOtherAttribute": "Cuz it's awesome", "someAttribute": "I am record two"},
{"someOtherAttribute": "Yup, still AJAX", "someAttribute": "I am record three"}
]
```

Which is [right out of the tutorial](http://www.dynatable.com/#existing-json).

I'm assuming it's my $.getJSON that's wrong. Should I be using a success and failure case? What would that look like? Should I be using parseJSON?

Thanks a lot, Alex

Comment: You have a syntax error -- `{ records: data; }`. Remove the semicolon after `data`, as they're not expected directly inside `Object` literals.

Comment: Thanks, fixed above. It still doesn't seem to work though - no data is loaded into the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I changed the javascript to this and it worked:

```
<script>
$.getJSON('/dynatable-ajax.json', function (response) {     
  $('#my-table').dynatable({
  dataset: {
    records: response
  },
});

});
</script>
```

Not entirely sure what was wrong with the first version, I think there are too many bracket closes or something.

Answer (score 0):

For really quick things like taht its helpful to use a site called  http://www.dirtymarkup.com

Paste your code in and click on each bracket, it then highlights the corresponding closing bracket.

http://jsbeautifier.org/ is another good site for adding indentation to see your code more clearly and http://www.javascriptlint.com/ for errors.